# Why can't I do barbell curls?

Tags: barbell

I am able to do, with heavier weights, concentration curl, hammer curl, and preacher curl with little difficulty, but when I do barbell curls I get exhausted or it's like there is no stamina in me. I think I involve my upper back and, due to lack of muscle and strength there, I feel tired. I heard that neurons are released when we get used to an exercise and we are able to perform it efficiently. What can you say on this matter?

Can running daily or a day in week increase my stamina? I am tall about 5 feet and inches.

Comment: Is it an overall fatigue? In your shoulders? Your arm? Your back? Where are you feeling the strain as you lift?

Comment: mostly in back.i am unable to stand and do barbell curls

Comment: Have you tried to do this exercise as the first of the day? or at least the first of biceps? Unless you have been training you arms for a year and didn't touched your back, you should have enough muscle.

Comment: stop doing curls and do real barbell strength training. it will make you stronger and ultimately your biceps bigger. my own biceps are plenty big and i haven't wasted time curling in 10 years. but i can do chinups with 90lbs danging from a chain belt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you answered the question yourself. Train your back. Some Romanian deadlifting and Band pull-aparts will solve your problem quickly. As you are wanting to get some strength, low heavy reps with multiple sets will do the trick.